# Microsoft CRM 2016: Trying to query the asyncoperation entity through sdk / SQL. Not able to see the Workflowstate field

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I've been trying to troubleshoot some failed workflow issues.  One of the things I'm doing is querying the asyncoperation entity through the sdk.

When I view the Data field of an AsyncOperation record I can see the xml representation of AsyncOperationData.  This is great!

However when I try to view the WorkflowState field of the AsyncOperation through the sdk, I always get a NULL back, even though I can verify that it's non-null through a sql query.

1) Has anyone encountered this issue before?

2) Does anyone know how to read the unencrypted versions of the following fields from this sql query:

SELECT ao.Data, ao.WorkflowState
FROM dbo.AsyncOperation ao

Comment: Post some code!

Answer (score 3):

That field is not queryable via the API. If you add it to a fetch query or query expression you'll get back the error:

> Retrieve can only return columns that are valid for read. Column :
>   workflowstate. Entity : asyncoperation

Similarly if you write a metadata query for `asyncoperation` and look at the `IsValidForRead` property of `workflowstate` it is false. Assuming you're using a custom workflow activity perhaps you could add some [logging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328574.aspx) to it and check those to help debug.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response Matt!  Are you aware of a way I can query it using SQL?

Comment: @Kronos888 I'm not. Might make sense to post the error you are trying to debug and see if someone has any advice.